# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at AuraInstance.message

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Has anyone faced below error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' 
    of null at AuraInstance.message
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

even I removed the things from component and made doInIt method empty then also I am getting error.

P.S:- When I remove handler tag then this error disappears. quite strange for me.

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
```

Comment: Please share the whole code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the mistake. I forgot to implement force:hasRecordId in the component, due to that it was causing the error.

Comment: It would be helpful to include in the question the code that caused the error as well as including in this answer the code that fixed it.